# Multilingual interface with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using `angular-translate` for my app , there is situation that i don't know how to handle this .
i want to translate something in controller like this :

**controller**:

```
 $scope.liveHint = function (param) {

if ($scope.setActionType === 1) {          
            $scope.text = "something";
  }         
else if($scope.setActionType === 2){

 $scope.text = "something New";
}
}
```

**Html**

```
<p ng-show="text">{{text}} </p>
```

I dont know how to translate with conditions .

Any Idea ?

Comment: That statement is just wrong - there's no such thing as `else` with a condition - you mean `else if`?

Comment: inject $filter and call `$scope.text = $filter('translate')('something')` if you don't want to do `{{text|translate}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in multiple ways

**Translate in controller**

inject $translate service in your controller

```
if($scope.setActionType === 1) {
    $scope.text = $translate.instant("key_name_of_something")
}
else {
    $scope.text = $translate.instant("key_name_for_something_new")
}
```

translating using service is asynchronous, although we can use $translate.instant but change it according to your need

documentation - http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service

View

```
<p ng-show="text">{{text}} </p>
```

**Translate in view**

Controller

```
if($scope.setActionType === 1) {
    $scope.text = "key_name_of_something"
}
else {
    $scope.text = "key_name_for_something_new"
}
```

View

```
<p ng-show="text">{{text | translate}} </p>
or
may be this will also work, you can try
<p ng-show="text" translate>{{text}}</p>
```

docs

http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/04_using-translate-filter

http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive

Comment: I don't have any context regarding ng-grid. I looked it up and I think it can be done using $translate service while assigning $scope.gridOptions